# Arrange JSON array data into html elements

Tags: jquery, html

i have JSON data like this :

```
{"_id":"56af2ca2eb91bd4721443037","username":"xxxxxx","userGroup":[{"groupName":"nodeJs","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b086ccd1bc72eb21d99c62"},{"0":{"groupName":"php","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0880d13c9fc4c22a1d291"}},{"0":{"groupName":"android","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0883513c9fc4c22a1d292"}},{"0":{"groupName":"ios","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0883913c9fc4c22a1d293"}},{"0":{"groupName":"dotNet","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0884213c9fc4c22a1d294"}},{"0":{"groupName":"testing","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0885913c9fc4c22a1d295"}},{"0":{"groupName":"design","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0886213c9fc4c22a1d296"}}]}
```

and i want to arrange the data in html elements like :

```html
<label>username</label> <label>groupName1</label> <input type = 'checkbox' checked /> <label>groupName2</label> <input type = 'checkbox' checked />
```

.....
except username, groupName and checkbox having more than one instance. how append this in one `<li>` tag

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: your first group doesn't have  a "0" preceding the group name

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var x = {"_id":"56af2ca2eb91bd4721443037","username":"xxxxxx","userGroup":[{"0":{"groupName":"nodeJs","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b086ccd1bc72eb21d99c62"}},{"0":{"groupName":"php","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0880d13c9fc4c22a1d291"}},{"0":{"groupName":"android","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0883513c9fc4c22a1d292"}},{"0":{"groupName":"ios","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0883913c9fc4c22a1d293"}},{"0":{"groupName":"dotNet","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0884213c9fc4c22a1d294"}},{"0":{"groupName":"testing","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0885913c9fc4c22a1d295"}},{"0":{"groupName":"design","groupAssigned":"No","_id":"56b0886213c9fc4c22a1d296"}}]};
$('body').append('<label>'+x.username+'</label>');
$.each(x.userGroup,function(i,v){
 $('body').append('<label>'+v["0"].groupName+'</label> <input type ="checkbox" checked />');
 console.log(v)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4vxxenk3/1/

or without the modified json:

https://jsfiddle.net/4vxxenk3/2/